# How to fix hilt onAttach called multiple times with different Context! Hilt Fragments should not be retained (Viewpager with tablayout)

Tags: android, fragment, dagger-hilt, android-viewpager2, dragger

I am using viewpager2 with a tab layout, I have set up the hilt config in my project, and this crash is reproduced when 2nd time when page reload

```
import android.os.Bundle
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment
import androidx.viewpager2.adapter.FragmentStateAdapter
import com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayoutMediator
import com.zig.gps.R
import com.zig.gps.databinding.TabLayoutBinding
import dagger.hilt.android.AndroidEntryPoint

@AndroidEntryPoint
class TabLayoutDemo : Fragment() {

    private var _binding: TabLayoutBinding? = null

    // This property is only valid between onCreateView and
    // onDestroyView.
    private val binding get() = _binding!!
    override fun onCreateView(
            inflater: LayoutInflater,
            container: ViewGroup?,
            savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View {

        _binding = TabLayoutBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false)
        return binding.root
    }

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

        //renderViewPager
        binding.viewpager.adapter = object : FragmentStateAdapter(this) {

            override fun createFragment(position: Int): Fragment {
                return ResourceStore.pagerFragments[position]
            }

            override fun getItemCount(): Int {
                return ResourceStore.tabList.size
            }
        }
        TabLayoutMediator(binding.tabs, binding.viewpager) { tab, position ->
            tab.text = getString(ResourceStore.tabList[position])
        }.attach()
    }


    override fun onDestroyView() {
        super.onDestroyView()
        _binding = null
    }

}

interface ResourceStore {
    companion object {
        val tabList = listOf(
            R.string.Dashboard, R.string.Tracking, R.string.Fastags,R.string.Reports, R.string.Documents, R.string.Maintance, R.string.Alerts, R.string.Device
        )

        //do it like:
        //val anotherFrament = DashboardNew.create()

        val pagerFragments = listOf(
            DashboardNew.create() ,
            DashboardNew.create() ,
            DashboardNew.create() ,
            DashboardNew.create() ,
            DashboardNew.create() ,
            DashboardNew.create() ,
            DashboardNew.create() ,
            DashboardNew.create() )
    }
}
```

Here is my fragment

```
import android.os.Bundle
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment
import androidx.fragment.app.viewModels
import dagger.hilt.android.AndroidEntryPoint


@AndroidEntryPoint
class DashboardNew : Fragment() {

    private var _binding: UserDashboardNewBinding? = null

    // This property is only valid between onCreateView and
    // onDestroyView.
    private val binding get() = _binding!!


    val viewModel: DashboardViewModel by viewModels()

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?,
    ): View {

        _binding = UserDashboardNewBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false)
        return binding.root

    }

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

    }
    
    companion object {
        fun create(): DashboardNew {
            return DashboardNew()
        }
    }

    override fun onDestroyView() {
        super.onDestroyView()
        _binding = null
    }
}
```

**Here is my crash:**

> FATAL EXCEPTION: main
> Process: com.zig.gps, PID: 13163
> java.lang.IllegalStateException: onAttach called multiple times with
> different Context! Hilt Fragments should not be retained.
> at
> dagger.hilt.internal.Preconditions.checkState(Preconditions.java:83)
> at
> com.zig.gps.view.Hilt_DashboardNew.onAttach(Hilt_DashboardNew.java:58)
> at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.onAttach(Fragment.java:1881)
> at
> com.zig.gps.view.Hilt_DashboardNew.onAttach(Hilt_DashboardNew.java:47)
> at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.performAttach(Fragment.java:3063)
> at
> androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.attach(FragmentStateManager.java:464)
> at
> androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.moveToExpectedState(FragmentStateManager.java:254)
> at
> androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.executeOpsTogether(FragmentManager.java:1890)
> at
> androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.removeRedundantOperationsAndExecute(FragmentManager.java:1808)
> at
> androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.execSingleAction(FragmentManager.java:1720)
> at
> androidx.fragment.app.BackStackRecord.commitNow(BackStackRecord.java:317)
> at
> androidx.viewpager2.adapter.FragmentStateAdapter.placeFragmentInViewHolder(FragmentStateAdapter.java:341)
> at
> androidx.viewpager2.adapter.FragmentStateAdapter.onViewAttachedToWindow(FragmentStateAdapter.java:276)
> at
> androidx.viewpager2.adapter.FragmentStateAdapter.onViewAttachedToWindow(FragmentStateAdapter.java:67)
> at
> androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchChildAttached(RecyclerView.java:7556)
> at
> androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$5.addView(RecyclerView.java:860)
> at
> androidx.recyclerview.widget.ChildHelper.addView(ChildHelper.java:107)
> at
> androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$LayoutManager.addViewInt(RecyclerView.java:8601)
> at
> androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$LayoutManager.addView(RecyclerView.java:8559)
> at
> androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$LayoutManager.addView(RecyclerView.java:8547)
> at
> androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager.layoutChunk(LinearLayoutManager.java:1641)
> at
> androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager.fill(LinearLayoutManager.java:1587)
> at
> androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager.onLayoutChildren(LinearLayoutManager.java:665)
> at
> androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayoutStep2(RecyclerView.java:4134)
> at
> androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayout(RecyclerView.java:3851)
> at
> androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.onLayout(RecyclerView.java:4404)
> at android.view.View.layout(View.java:23126)
> at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6479)
> at
> androidx.viewpager2.widget.ViewPager2.onLayout(ViewPager2.java:527)
> at android.view.View.layout(View.java:23126)
> at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6479)
> at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1829)
> at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1673)
> at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1582)
> at android.view.View.layout(View.java:23126)
> at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6479)
> at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:332)
> at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:270)
> at android.view.View.layout(View.java:23126)
> at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6479)
> at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:332)
> at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:270)
> at android.view.View.layout(View.java:23126)
> at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6479)
> at
> androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout.onLayout(ConstraintLayout.java:1762)
> at android.view.View.layout(View.java:23126)
> at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6479)
> at
> com.google.android.material.appbar.HeaderScrollingViewBehavior.layoutChild(HeaderScrollingViewBehavior.java:148)
> at
> com.google.android.material.appbar.ViewOffsetBehavior.onLayoutChild(ViewOffsetBehavior.java:43)
> 2022-10-22 12:10:02.529 13163-13163 AndroidRuntime
> com.zig.gps                          E    at
> com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout$ScrollingViewBehavior.onLayoutChild(AppBarLayout.java:2227)
> at
> androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout.onLayout(CoordinatorLayout.java:918)
> at android.view.View.layout(View.java:23126)
> at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6479)
> at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:332)
> at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:270)
> at android.view.View.layout(View.java:23126)
> at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6479)
> at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1829)
> at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1673)
> at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1582)
> at android.view.View.layout(View.java:23126)
> at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6479)
> at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:332)
> at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:270)
> at android.view.View.layout(View.java:23126)
> at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6479)
> at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1829)
> at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1673)
> at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1582)
> at android.view.View.layout(View.java:23126)
> at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6479)
> at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:332)
> at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:270)
> at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.onLayout(DecorView.java:804)
> at android.view.View.layout(View.java:23126)
> at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6479)
> at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performLayout(ViewRootImpl.java:3630)
> at
> android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:3089)
> at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:2079)
> at
> android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:8526)
> at
> android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:1077)
> at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:897)
> at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:826)
> at
> android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:1062)
> at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938)
> at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
> at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:233)
> at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8052)
> at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
> at
> com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:656)
> at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:967)

Hilt onAttach called multiple times with different Contexts! Hilt Fragments should not be retained

**Source code**: https://github.com/BoltUIX/Hilt-Demo-Viewpager-with-tablayout

**Crash Reproduce**: https://github.com/BoltUIX/Hilt-Demo-Viewpager-with-tablayout/blob/main/22-11-02-14-00-40.mp4

Comment: Why is your `createFragment` returning static instances of Fragments? Of course that means you are reusing fragment instances. `createFragment` needs to create a brand new fragment instance every time it is called.

Comment: In other terms, replace `DashboardNew.create()` with `DashboardNew()`.

Comment: I'm facing the same problem, did you resolve it following these recommendations?